# LINQ GroupBy and project to type with both a list of its keys and result of ToDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a conditional form where a user can select a geographical boundary type (e.g. "Town" and "District") and based on that selection the user can choose a corresponding entity (e.g. `"Town" => ["Town 1", "Town 2"]`, `"District" => ["District 1", "District 2"]`)

I was thinking my API can return an object that looks like:

```
{
  "BoundaryTypes": ["Town", "District"],
  "Boundaries": {
    "Town": [
      { "Id": 1, "Name": "Town 1" },
      { "Id": 1, "Name": "Town 2" }
    ],
    "District": [
      { "Id": 1, "Name": "District 1" },
      { "Id": 1, "Name": "District 2" }
    ]
  }
}
```

I unioned all my Boundary tables -- Towns, Districts, etc -- to create a database view like:

```
| BundaryType | BoundaryId | BoundaryName |
|-------------|------------|--------------|
| Town        | 1          | Town 1       |
| Town        | 2          | Town 2       |
| District    | 1          | District 1   |
| District    | 2          | District 2   |
```

My current attempt in the process only gets one part of the solution, but I'm at a loss to get something like the API result I proposed:

```
var result = await context.Boundaries
                .GroupBy(boundary => boundary.BoundaryType)
                .ToDictionaryAsync(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

return Ok(result);
```

The returned object doesn't have to be so terse, it can have the full entities, just wrote as such for brevity. **The main thing I'm trying to learn to do is:**

```
BoundaryTypes = list,
Boundaries = dictionary
```

Comment: A couple thoughts... I would normalize the boundary type and create a separate table for it.  BoundaryType is an attribute of Boundary.  The problem as stated above really points to this step as you want to data sets anyway (BoundaryTypes and Boundaries), making them two tables makes sense.  Keys in Dictionaries need to be unique, as such, having two BoundaryIds with a BoundaryId of 1 won't work unless you made a composite key, but that won't give you the JSON you want.  Separate the tables, then you can return them similar to @Guru's response below.

Comment: The original pre-existing entities I worked with actually had a separate table for each boundary type. I created a view that just unions all the boundary tables. Would that slightly alter how you propose to arrange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types):

```cs
return Ok(new
{
  BoundaryTypes = result.Keys,
  Boundaries = result
}
);
```

or create a type representing this data structure:

```
public class Response
{
    public List<string> BoundaryTypes  { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Boundary> Boundaries { get; set; }
}
```

And use it:

```cs
return Ok(new Response
{
  BoundaryTypes = result.Keys,
  Boundaries = result
}
);
```

Comment: Haha, I was so deadset on trying to write a single LINQ statement I didn't think of doing something simple like this...